# Action toolbar, mysterious gap android

Tags: android, android-layout

i have no idea what's the problem is this .. but this is disgusting and make my app look so bad ..

here a screenshot of the problem

[image]

i don't know where it is come from...
i give you my tool bar XML

**Toolbar.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton" />
```

i show it on my `mainActivity` layout.. and this is my `mainActivity` layout

**ContentMain.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.study.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.study.fragment.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

BUT this problem `dissapear` if i went to another fragment and go back to home fragment

[image]

i've tried re-install the apps .. and rebuild project .. build clean project .. it doesn't work

that images show from fragment which implemented in `frameLayout`, and in my fragment there's a slider show images.

FragmentHome.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.study.fragment.HomeFragment">

            <com.example.study.slider_library.SliderLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
                custom:auto_cycle="true"
                custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
                custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
                android:background="#202020"
                android:drawingCacheQuality="auto" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this one java code of my `FragmentHome`

HomeFragment.Java

```
public class HomeFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
        implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener, ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener {


    private HashMap<String,String> url_maps;
    private SliderLayout mDemoSlider;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.slider);


        HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<>();

        url_maps.put("Hannibal", "http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/hannibal-season-2-release-date.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Big Bang Theory", "http://tvfiles.alphacoders.com/100/hdclearart-10.png");
        url_maps.put("House of Cards", "http://cdn3.nflximg.net/images/3093/2043093.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Game of Thrones", "http://images.boomsbeat.com/data/images/full/19640/game-of-thrones-season-4-jpg.jpg");


        for(String name : url_maps.keySet()){
            DefaultSliderView DefaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(getContext());
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            DefaultSliderView
                    .image(url_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

            //add your extra information
            DefaultSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            DefaultSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra",name);

            mDemoSlider.addSlider(DefaultSliderView);
        }

        mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Tablet);
        mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        mDemoSlider.setDuration(400);
        mDemoSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return layout;

    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        // To prevent a memory leak on rotation, make sure to call stopAutoCycle() on the slider before activity or fragment is destroyed
        mDemoSlider.stopAutoCycle();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),slider.getBundle().get("extra") + "",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.d("Slider Demo", "Page Changed: " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is all your XML files because I am not seeing how that image is being displayed

Comment: oohh .. that's image is slider(slideshow) .. i've update more information how it happened .. that's the XML show layout on main activity .. that image show from home fragment which show on frame layout below toolbar

Comment: try set `android:id="@+id/container_body"` to background red, then white line still appear or not?

Comment: @PhanVănLinh change to red as you said.. is it problem with my container / fragment layout .. ?

Comment: Might be because of elevation in your toolbar? Which API are you running the app on?

Comment: @KevinMurvie API 22 .. don't know what to do, and what's the problem .. there's no error warning .. works fine . .but show that gap

Comment: How are you rendering the image into the `ImageView`? Can you show the Java codes?

Comment: @KevinMurvie updated .. it's more complicated than i expected,

Comment: I can't seem to see where's the mistake.. Maybe image's cropping? Try using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` << I forgot how it's written but this is close

Comment: @KevinMurvie may be correct, try using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` or `fitXY`